# How to remove an object by value from a set

Tags: python, python-3.x, object

I have a set of Point objects, and I would like to be able to remove these objects from my set. However, Python seems to be comparing these by pointer rather than by value, so I can't remove elements easily, since they don't have the same pointer because they are not the exact same object. This is a problem only with objects, not with primitives.

A simplified example of my problem:

```
class Point():
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

a = set()
a.add(Point(0, 0))
b = Point(0, 0)
a.remove(b)
```

When run, this returns

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "example.py", line 9, in <module>
    a.remove(b)
KeyError: <__main__.Point object at 0x7f6292376128>
```

(obviously, the specific pointer changes on each run).

I would prefer to have the element `(0, 0)` removed from `a`, leaving `a` to be the empty set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you tell Python how to compare these objects, this can work.  Add two methods like:

#### Code:

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    return self.x == other.x and self.y == other.y

def __hash__(self):
    return hash((self.x, self.y))
```

#### Test Code:

```
class Point():
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.x == other.x and self.y == other.y

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash((self.x, self.y))


a = set()
a.add(Point(0, 0))
b = Point(0, 0)
a.remove(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

It does not appear that you have actually added Point b to the set 'a'.
According to the docs:

> If the element(argument) passed to the remove() method doesn't exist, keyError exception is thrown.

I made this slight alteration and it didn't error out

```
class Point():
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

a = set()
a.add(Point(0, 0))
b = Point(0, 0)
a.add(b)
a.remove(b)
```

Comment: No, what is asked is how can we remove `Point(0,0)` from the set `a`, since, as we see, the value of `b` equals the value of `Point(0,0)`.